# mdadm confused on minor number

Tags: mdadm, device

Recently replaced a faulty disk in my Raid 6 group.  All went as expected, no problem.  After getting everything rebuilt using a new /dev/sdi1 as a replacement for the failing /dev/sde1 I decided to try an unplug /dev/sde1.  I guessed wrong. I powered down and plugged what I'm now guessing was /dev/sdh's SATA cable back in and powered back up.

/dev/sdh1 is now refusing to be added back into the array, giving me the classic "Device or Resource busy" message when I either try to assemble or hotadd it in.

Digging around, it appears to be confusing /dev/sdh1 with /dev/sdg1:

fs1 etc # mdadm --examine /dev/sdh1
/dev/sdh1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 95b6add0:acea3231:a1c8af6a:322d8026
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 16 06:40:57 2008
     Raid Level : raid6
  Used Dev Size : 732571904 (698.64 GiB 750.15 GB)
     Array Size : 3662859520 (3493.18 GiB 3750.77 GB)
   Raid Devices : 7
  Total Devices : 7
Preferred Minor : 0

```
Update Time : Sat Dec  7 11:00:34 2013  
      State : clean
```

Active Devices : 7
Working Devices : 7
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 86c78a1c - correct
         Events : 522025

```
     Layout : left-symmetric  
 Chunk Size : 64K  

  Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
```

this     3       8       97        3      active sync   /dev/sdg1

0     0       8        9        0      active sync   /dev/sda9
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       81        2      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   3     3       8       97        3      active sync   /dev/sdg1
   4     4       8       33        4      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   5     5       8       49        5      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   6     6       8      113        6      active sync   /dev/sdh1

Note that "this" is showing as having the same Minor number as /dev/sdg1.  Doing an "mdadm --examine" on any other element works as expected, with "this" displaying the minor number that matches the partition.

ugh... looking at all the "mdadm --examines" things look even funkier.  Most are showing /dev/sda3 (by minor number) as a fault drive even though /dev/sde1 (minor 65) was the one faulted and removed.  /dev/sde1 is now showing as a spare.  Up through /dev/sdg1 otherwise look OK, but /dev/sdh1 is reporting as having the same minor number as /dev/sdg1, and /dev/sdi1 is reporting as having the same minor number as /dev/sdh1.

How can I get this corrected?  I tried zeroing the front of the /dev/sdh disk and recreating partitions but that didn't help.

I do have a backup of the data, although its on a single disk at the moment.  Still, I even attempted to recreate the array, but still get the "device or resource busy":

mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=6 --raid-devices=7 /dev/sda9 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1
mdadm: /dev/sda9 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid6 devices=7 ctime=Sat Aug 16 06:40:57 2008
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid6 devices=7 ctime=Sat Aug 16 06:40:57 2008
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid6 devices=7 ctime=Sat Aug 16 06:40:57 2008
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid6 devices=7 ctime=Sat Aug 16 06:40:57 2008
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid6 devices=7 ctime=Sat Aug 16 06:40:57 2008
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sdh1: Device or resource busy
mdadm: /dev/sdh1 is not suitable for this array.
mdadm: /dev/sdi1 appears to be part of a raid array :
    level=raid6 devices=7 ctime=Sat Aug 16 06:40:57 2008
mdadm: create aborted

Comment: Just an FYI, but: